# Ajax trouble: Sending a list to django with json

Tags: python, ajax, django

It feels like I'm missing something simple here but i just can't figure it out.
I get a HTTP error 500 code when i try my ajax call.

Here's the relevant code:

From js

```
$('#btn-analyze').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/TestData/analyze',
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(selected),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

From urls.py

```
url(r'^analyze/$', analyze.as_view(), name='analyze'),
```

From views.py

```
class analyze(View):

def get(self, request):
    print("get started")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def post(self, request):
    print("Post started")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I think this may be a stupid way to achieve what I want anyway. I just want to be able to send an array from javascript to a view and be able to redirect with that information. Might be easier/smarter to do with a form and somehow send the array with it than ajax. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The `post` method should not take the `request` parameter. That's taken by the base View class's `dispatch` method and assigned to an instance variable.

Comment: Still get a 500 error. Could it have something to do with Post and csrf-token? Because I managed to enter the get method when I used Type:'GET' instead.

Comment: No, that would be a 403. Can you look in the browser's dev tools to find the actual error?

Comment: From the javascript console:`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/TestData/analyze 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) jquery.min.js:4send jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) TestData.js:174m.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3r.handle jquery.min.js:3`  TestData.js:174 is the ajax call

Comment: But if you click on the Network tab, you'll see the details of the failed Ajax call, complete with the actual rendered response which will be the Django error page.

Comment: Ahh! Apparantley I had forgotten the last slash in the url and when I added that I get a 403 error instead with this in the response: `<p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
    </pre>`. But I still think I may be approaching this problem the wrong way. I just need to get hold of my selected array in my view to be able to redirect to another page and do stuff.